# 1-D Fourier Transform Of A 2-D Image But At An Arbitrary Orientation

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, fft

If one has a 2-D array and would like to take the 1-D Fourier transform along a direction theta degrees off the horizontal, is there a better/faster way to do this rather than rotating the image by −theta degrees, taking the 1-D FT across the columns, and then rotating the result back by theta degrees?